# Problemas con sqlsrv_errors en php

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, sql-server-2014

Estoy usando PHP 5.6 sobre IIS 10 con SQL Server 2014, y tengo la siguiente función para hacer inserts, updates y deletes a la base de datos:

```
<?php
public function ejecutarSQL($sql,$parametrosSQLServer=array()){
    $bandera=false;
    $msg="";
    $datos=array();
    $nowRows=0;
    $datos_pr=array();
    $cadena_replace="";
    if( $this->conexion){
        $parametros =array();
        if(count($parametrosSQLServer)>=1){
            foreach($parametrosSQLServer as $key => &$value) {
                $parametros[] = &$value;
            }
            $resultado=sqlsrv_prepare( $this->conexion,$sql,$parametros);
        }else{
            $resultado=sqlsrv_prepare( $this->conexion,$sql,$parametros);
        }
        $result= sqlsrv_execute($resultado);
        if($result != false){
            $nowRows=sqlsrv_rows_affected($resultado);
            if($nowRows ==1){
                $rst=sqlsrv_query($this->conexion,"SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID ");
                $row =  sqlsrv_fetch_array($rst);
                if ($row["ID"] == null){
                    $datos[] =  "Registro exitoso";
                }else{
                    $datos[] =  $row["ID"];
                }
                sqlsrv_free_stmt($rst);
                $bandera=true;
                sqlsrv_free_stmt($resultado);
            }else{
                $bandera=false;
                $msg = sqlsrv_errors();//Esta linea siempre devuelve null aun con registros intencionalmente duplicados
                $nowRows=0;
                $msg=$msg[1]['message'];
                sqlsrv_free_stmt($resultado);
            }
        }else{
            $bandera= false;
            $nowRows=0;
            $msg = sqlsrv_errors();
            $msg=$msg[0]['message'];
        }
    }
    if ($bandera==true){
        return array(true, $nowRows, $datos);
    }else{
        return array(false, $nowRows, $msg);
    }
}
```

El código funciona correctamente para hacer las operaciones. Lo que no funciona correctamente es la función sqlsrv_errors() ya que al mandar inserts con registros duplicados, esta función siempre me regresa null, y no puedo ver una descripcion del error (la cual necesito).

Lei que sqlsrv_errors() solo devuelve errores y no warnings, asi que modifique la configuración para que me devolviera los warnings como errores, pero el problema continua:

```
$this->datosConexion=@parse_ini_file($rutaProperties, false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
    $this->schema=$this->datosConexion["SsqlsvrSchema"];
    $this->serverName = $this->datosConexion["SsqlsvrNombreServidor"]."\MSSQLSERVER,".$this->datosConexion["SsqlsvrPuerto"];
    $this->parametros = array( "Database"=> $this->datosConexion["SsqlsvrBaseDatos"] ,"UID"=> $this->datosConexion["SsqlsvrUsuario"] , "PWD"=>$this->datosConexion["SsqlsvrPass"], "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
    sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors',0);//Esta es la linea que agregue
    $this->conexion = sqlsrv_connect( $this->serverName, $this->parametros);
    if($this->conexion) {
        return (true);
    }else{
         return(false);
    }
```

¿Alguien sabe como resolverlo?¿Será configuración del php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

La documentación de `sqlsrv_errors()` indica que las alertas son tratadas como errores pero coloca algunas excepciones a la regla, lo que lo hace confuso de entender. Podrías probar alterando los parámetros de las dos funciones para ver si alguna combinación te sirve. Es decir, probar las siguientes combinaciones:

1. `sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ERRORS)` y `sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0)`.
2. `sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ERRORS)` y `sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 1)`.
3. `sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_WARNINGS)` y `sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0)`.
4. `sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_WARNINGS)` y `sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 1)`.

La documentación de Microsoft ([Cómo controlar errores y advertencias con el controlador SQLSRV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc644937(v=sql.105).aspx))  tiene un ejemplo bien detallado y puede servirte de ayuda.

Comment: He probado todos los casos y sigue regresando null. Lo extraño es que la llamada `$msg = sqlsrv_errors();` que esta en el `}else{` del `if($result != false){` si regresa el error correctamente cuando introduzco un error de sintaxis en el query

Comment: el problema al parecer solo ocurre cuando intento insertar un registro duplicado